# Deserialize Nested Json Record From Postgres To POJO using Jackson

Tags: python, java, jackson, deserialization, pojo

I am preety new to Jackson and how it really works under the hood when its get complicated to an issue of what i am facing. I have a record coming from the database which is stored as JSON TYPE (using postgres). Below is a sample of how it is in the database:
`{"flutterwave": {"secret": "SECRET KEYS"}, "dlocal": {"xkey": X KEY VALUE", "xlogin": "X LOGIN VALUE"}}`

Coming from python world, i would have just done `json.loads(DATA_FROM_DB_IN_JSON)` and it automatically converts the resulting output to a Dictionary in which i can easily retrieve and utilize the keys as i want them, However with Jackson library of Java, i haven't been able to get it to work.

Below is what i have done in java and haven't gotten it to work the way i would have expected it if were python.

```java
public class PaymentConfigDTO {

    @JsonAlias({"secrets"})
    @JsonDeserialize(using = KeepAsJsonDeserializer.class)
    private String processorCredentials;
}
```

DESERIALIZER CLASS

```java
public class KeepAsJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {
    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JacksonException {
        TreeNode tree = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
        return tree.toString();
    }
}
```

In summary, what i want to acheive is been able to convert the result json coming from the db to deserializable to a Map<String, Map<>> or a better approach where i will be able to get the nested values without much stress.

Comment: So i solved the issue by changing the TreeNode at the serializer class to utilise a JsonNode instead.

So overall, the custom deserializer class was re-written to: 
```javapublic class KeepAsJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {
    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JacksonException {
        TreeNode tree = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
        return tree.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you already have Json String it is very simple to deserialize it to Map<String, Object>. you don't need to write your own deserializer class. All you need to do is:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
try {
  Map<String, Object> map = om.readValue(jsonStr, Map.class);
} catch(IOException ioe) {
...
}
```

See JavaDoc for [ObjectMapper](https://javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.14.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html)
Also, if you want it even simpler I wrote my own JsonUtil where you don't even have to instantiate ObjectMapper. Your code would look like this:

```
 try {
    Map<String, Object> map = JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString(jsonStr, Map.class);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ...
}
```

In this example class `JsonUtils` comes with Open Source MgntUtils library written and maintained by me. See [the Javadoc for JsonUtils class](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html). The MgntUtils library can be obtained from [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) as Maven artifact or from [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) along with Source code and Javadoc

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` you can do:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
...
var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
var result = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Map<String, String>>>() {});
```

But would be better to use types:

```java
record Config(Flutterwave flutterwave, DLocal dlocal) {}
record Flutterwave(String secret) {}
record DLocal(String xkey, String xlogin) {}
...
var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
var result = mapper.readValue(json, Config.class);
var secret = result.flutterwave().secret()
```

Answer (score 0):

So what i did basically was to update the custom deserializer class to use a JsonNode instead of TreeNode

It was re-written as:

```java
@Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JacksonException {
        JsonNode node = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
        return node.get("value").textValue();
    }
```

Then to convert to a map, i did
`Map<String, Object> toMap = objectMapper.readValue(JSON, Map.class)`